# Time and space complexity of this Fibonacci solution

Tags: time-complexity, fibonacci

I was reading this article on fib solutions (very helpful): https://medium.com/@johanna.fulghum/write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-every-computational-complexity-9adf5ef12775

But is there a typo on her last solution time and space complexities?

```
function fib(n, a = 0, b = 1){
  if (n > 0) {
    return fib(n - 1, b, a + b)
  }
  return a
}
```

She says 'This tail recursive solution is constant O(n) time and constant O(n) space complexity. This can’t be beat'. She means O(1) for both right? Since O(n) is linear. Also, I see how it's O(1) space, but could someone explains why it's O(1) time? To me it appears like it's O(n) time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a typo (or an editing mistake), and the space complexity is also depending on compiler optimization to indeed be constant `O(1)`.

The complexity of this code is `Theta(n)` time, and space complexity could be `Theta(n)` or `Theta(1)`, depending if the compiler optimizes tail recursion to loop. If it does optimize tail recursion, then the code is basically equivalent to her solution 3.

```
function fibs(n){
  let [a, b] = [0, 1]
  while (n > 0){
    [a, b] = [b, a + b]
    n -= 1
  }
  return a
}
```

I also have concerns with the statement of `This can’t be beat`.

In fact, fibonacci has a [closed form formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula), which can be calculated using `O(logn)`, assuming multiplication is done in constant time.<sup>1</sup>

---

(1) If this assumption does not hold, and you in fact care about the complexity of arithmetic operations as well, this complicates the answer. Basically, this means your complexity depends on the size of the output, which also grows exponentially. Since this grows exponentially. Since it grows exponentially, you need `O(log(result))` bits to represent it, and then you get a lower bound of linear time, since the size of the output, itself is linear in `n`.